# MVC Controller method not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning Async/Await in MVC5. I created this demo app but my controller action method is not getting fired. Its giving "The resource cannot be found." error. Here is the code.

1. _Layout.cshtml view

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("ASYNC", "GetNames", "Async")
   ```
2. GetNames.cshtml view

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "GetFirstName", "Async", null,  new{@class = "btn btn-primary" })
   @if (ViewBag.FName != null)
   {
     <p>
        <label>@ViewBag.FName </label>
     </p>
   }
   ```
3. In AsyncController.cs file

   ```
   public ActionResult GetNames()
   {
       return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<ActionResult> GetFirstName()
   {
       var r = await GetFirstNameFromDB();
       ViewBag.FName = r;
       return View("GetNames");
   }
   public async Task<string> GetFirstNameFromDB()
   {
       try
       {
           var res = await Task.Run(() =>
           {
               Thread.Sleep(3000);
               return "TestFName";
           });

           return res;
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           return "Error in getting FirstName";
       }
   }
   ```

Now, whenever i click the action link button to call the `GetFirstName`, it shows `The resource cannot be found.` error. I'm not sure if it is related to action being `async` or something else.

Comment: Have you hit F12 to see what exactly is being called when you click the button?

Comment: `ActionLink` produces an `<a>` anchor tag. Clicking on these generates a GET request. However your action is marked `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: As Jasen mentioned. Change the HttpPost to HttpGet or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined an `ActionLink` which will perform a GET-request when you click on it.

The controller has the method `GetFirstName` defined as `HttpPost`. Changing this to `HttpGet` will make sure the action is available for GET-requests.

Comment: sometimes trying to learn big make you overlook small things :)